# Are a page's images calculated as requests in Dynamic IP Restrictions?

Tags: iis-7, dynamic-ip

Our site has performance issues, and spambots make it worse, so we decided to configure Dynamic IP Restrictions to allow only 5 concurrent requests (per one request per IP). My concern is that a single page may do many concurrent requests as it contains many images (we have like 20 images per one page), so will these be blocked? Are images calculated as request in Dynamic IP Restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, yes it's considered as request.

Comment: How did you "find it"? Is there some other source you referenced, or was it your own testing and experiences? Please elaborate on your answer so that others may learn as well.

Comment: I down voted this because it's a poor answer, especially considering it's a self answer.

Comment: It answers the question. I "found" it also by trying to open the website with IP restrictions enabled.

Comment: I did find it out the hard way - when my images and javascript files wouldn't load after I set my Dynamic IP Restrictions to 10 requests, so I think this is a good answer. I wish I saw this before I was haunted by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had to switch on Dynamic IP Restrictions after a brute force attack on our website. We started with the default numbers.

After performing a 'hard' refresh (CTRL+F5) in my browser, our homepage was half covered in broken images! A request for a single ASPX can trigger thirty image requests and several CSS/JS file requests too. All happening within a few milliseconds, all from the same IP.

Your settings need to allow for this. Sadly this means the hackers get more of a chance too.